# User settings in django admin

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I want to be able to change some settings from django admin, for example: site title or footer. I want to have app with model which includes this settings, but this settings should be in single copy. What the best way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a view with @staff_member_required decorator, which renders/saves a form:

```
from django.contrib.admin.views.decorators import staff_member_required
...
@staff_member_required
def edit_config(request, ):
    saved = False
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = ConfigForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            ...
            # Do saving here
            saved = True
    else:
        form = ConfigForm()
        ...
    context = {
        'form': form,
        'saved': saved,
    }
    return render_to_response('staff/edit_config.html', context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Use [django forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/) in the view, and pass it to the template.

then, in the template extend 'admin/base_site.html' so your form has a admin look and feel. Here's a sample template:

```
{% extends 'admin/base_site.html' %}
{% load i18n adminmedia %}

{% block title %}Edit Configuration {{ block.super }} {% endblock %}

{% block extrastyle %}{{ block.super }}<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% admin_media_prefix %}css/forms.css" />{% endblock %}

{% block breadcrumbs %}
    <div class="breadcrumbs">
        <a href="/admin/">{% trans "Home" %}</a> > Edit Configuration
    </div>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>Edit Configuration</h1>
    {% if saved %}
        <p class="success" style="background-color:#9F9; padding: 10px; border: 1px dotted #999;">
            Settings were saved successfully!
        </p>
    {% endif %}
    <form method="POST" action="">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <fieldset class="module aligned">
            <h2>Configuration</h2>
            <div class="description"></div>
            {% for field in form %}
                <div class="form-row {% if field.errors %}errors{% endif %}">
                    {{ field.errors }}
                    <div class="field-box">
                        {{ field.label }} : {{ field }}
                        {% if field.help_text %}
                            <p class="help">{{ field.help_text|safe }}</p>
                        {% endif %}
                    </div>
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
        </fieldset>
        <div class="submit-row">
            <input type="submit" value="{% trans 'Save' %}" class="default" name="_save"/>
        </div>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

You can use database, ini files, redis, ... for storing your configuration. You may define some general backend, and inherit your custom backends from it so it's flexible.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like [django-constance](https://github.com/comoga/django-constance#readme) would be a good fit.

Though [django-flatblocks](https://github.com/zerok/django-flatblocks) might be sufficient.

> django-flatblocks is a simple application for handling small
>   text-blocks on websites. Think about it like django.contrib.flatpages
>   just not for a whole page but for only parts of it, like an
>   information text describing what you can do on a site.

Comment: I don't want to use third-party applications. Can I do this without third-party applications?

Comment: Of course you could create a model that holds the data you need and then create a template tag that renders the data at the appropriate places. But as you already indicated this solution you should probably clarify your exact question/problem. Then again, what keeps you from using a third party app in this case? Flatblocks pretty much does what you you want and as there are already some people using it you can be sure that it considers problems/aspects you don't realize at the moment. At least you could look at it's source to draw some inspirations for your own solution.